# Openpyxl enumerating over NoneType cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

My goal is to open a spreadsheet that had mismatched data entries and iterate through them row by row within the column to then process the information. When iterating with a for loop with `range(2, ws.max_row)`, the iteration continues past the last instance of data (cell a36) and keeps iterating and returning None beyond where I would expect the ws.max_row argument to stop at cell a36.

This is what I tried:

```
for cell in range(2, ws.max_row):
   value = ws.cell(row=cell, column=1).value
   print(value)
```

The output displays the cell values containing data and then after cell a36 it continues to output empty cells such as:

```
DPS ‐ Hot Springs ‐ 206 S Chicago Street 
None
None
None
None
None
```

A36 is the last cell containing any data and I thought that max_row was equivalent to the last row containing data. Does anyone understand what could be causing my for loop to continue afterwards?

Comment: ***I thought that max_row was equivalent to the last row containing data.***: That's not True, a *Worksheet* can have up to `.max_row`, rows with `None` data.

Comment: What value does `max_row` have? Maybe there are values in other columns? Or formatting has been applied. `max_row` is a convenience only and you can assume worksheets have a million rows unless you have reason to think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are fully populated up till the last row (in your case row 36), why not use a while loop and a break condition?

Something along the lines of this:

```
row = 2
while True:
    value = ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value
    print(value)
    if value == None:
        break
    row += 1
```

As stated by @stovfl and @Charlie Clark, `max_row` isn't necessarily the last row in your data that isn't `None`. Better to be explicit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ur excel file had edited several NoneType cells beyond the last data cell that u expected.

There r 2 ways to solve it.

1. Set a `break` in ur loop when the `cell.value` equals what u r expected.
2. Check ur excel file if it has NoneType cells that u unexpected.